# Sending receiving data in socket.io

Tags: html, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am new to socket.io and trying to replicate the example given at http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
        <style>
          * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
          body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
          form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
          form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
          form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
          #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
          #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
          #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
        </style>

        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
          var socket = io();
          $('form').submit(function(){
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <form action="">
          <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>

    var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.sendfile('index.html');
    });
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
       console.log('message pinged--------------');
       socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('chat message ' + msg);
      });
      socket.on('message', function(obj){
        console.log("meg from server");
      });

    });

    http.listen(8079, function(){
      console.log('listening on *:8079');
    });
    console.log('Server is running...dnt worry!!');

    {
      "name": "socket-chat-example",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "description": "my first socket.io app",
      "dependencies": {
        "express": "4.3.1",
        "socket.io": "1.0.2"
      }
    }
```

Message is not giving pinged..
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            console.log('chat message ' + msg);
          });

while i am able to know when the message is pinged but not what is pinged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work as expected because you add `submit` handler to non-existing form. The form is being created ***after*** your script is executed.

To fix this you should either wrap your js code in [document-ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function:

```
$(function() {
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
});
```

or put your js code to the very end of the `body` tag.

Comment: Do you see `chat message` in node's console when you send a message?

Comment: no i am not able to receive any message in node's console....only ping i m  getting when somebody send anything...but what they are sending..i m not getting

Comment: It started working...dnt know what was missing....thanks anyway...also document.ready was required...